# Seting Schema for HSQLDB in JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

How does one set the schema for HSQLDB in the JDBC URL itself.

Kinda how you can do in MySQL with jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

-EDIT-

My current DB url looks like this

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\hsqldb\\dbname
```

Also inside the dbanme there is a schema newSchema, which can be set using
set schema newSchema,
how do i do this using the jdbc URL itself.

Comment: You can change the start-up schema.  Normally with HSQLDB it is  _PUBLIC_.  Change with [SET INITIAL SCHEMA <schemaname>;](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#set_initialschema-section)  Within Java there's also a method on the connector to [setSchema()](http://hsqldb.org/doc/apidocs/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCConnection.html#setSchema(java.lang.String) -- That may get your what you need_??_

Answer (score 1):

have you already tried the standard protocol?
"jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://[HOST]:[PORT]/myDBName" 
How are you trying to connect? through a standalone app or by creating a resource?
You might have seen this but still check here if not done:
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_connection_url

Comment: already tried the recommendation.However the schema is inside the DBNAME.

Comment: Hmmm.  Me thinks there's a terminology issue.  A database such as, **dbname** shown in the example, _CONTAINS_ schemas.  Many people describe the _database_ and the _schema_ as the same-thing.  And often that's true.  Most places I've been we've only ever had one-schema-pre-database, hence the double meaning.  HSQLDB definitely works this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think need to specify the port number like as shown //192.0.0.10:9500

Comment: the issue is not about the port number .. rather how to set the schema name

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

I have been doing some more testing.  The suggested solution appears to be ineffective.

For example; if I set  the schema to `Test` I still ***may not*** use SQL on tables in that schema.  Essentially that extra stuff I put in there has no effect, even though I thought it was OK.

```
   select * from BOOKMARKS;
   SEVERE  SQL Error at '<stdin>' line 5:
   "select * from BOOKMARKS"
   user lacks privilege or object not found: BOOKMARKS
```

`SquirrelSQL` has an option for an initial schema, so queries there work OK.  The `sqlTool` accepts the URI but doesn't change/select the schema.  It is slightly frustrating that I can't see HOW to report the current schema name in use *btw*.

So this answer doesn't solve the problem; I'm leaving it here because it will save the next person time when they find a good answer to the challenge.

- *back to the drawing board ...*

### *original suggestion ...*

I'd like to do this too.  For example with mysql the example is:

```
mysql -h hostname:port schema
```

The port number, being one port per database.  Now in HSQLDB, the URL is one database within a Catalog (that's how they spell it).  Here's the solution I came-up with.  I have ...

- databsee: **dev**
- schemas

  - public
  - test

In my RC file, `~/.config/sqltool.rc` ...

```
  urlid dev_test
  url jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/dev;set schema test;
  username programmer
  password secret
```

I can use the connection ID *dev_test* to link to the `test` schema, the normal default is `public`.  And you can run the sql tool with:

```
  java -jar  /usr/lib/hsqldb/lib/sqltool.jar   --rcFile=~/.config/sqltool.rc  dev_tmp
```

That approach worked with a Groovy **Sql** connection:

```
url:  'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/dev;set schema test',
 ...
```

Worked just how I'd want it.  So what I can do is append the schema I want to that URL connection string string.  It may no be the solution but it will do what you describe.

Looking at the [connection protocol](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_connection_url):  there is NO option for a schema nor for a catalog.  So catalog will be part of your URL, eg. if you use a file base database, that is one catalog.